# PHP: Undefined index with checkboxes

Tags: php, html, undefined-index

I'm getting the following error all the time: 
The error depends on which checkbox has been checked.
The data passes through to the database but something is giving the error.
I guess I need to make a check first or change something?
The records in the table are set as boolean's.
What it needs to do is save the value of the checkbox (checked = 1 / not checked = 0) by pressing the submit button and save it in the database.
It does this but not without showing the errors.

```
>Notice: Undefined index: dekblad1_generfd in D:\Apps\Xampp\htdocs\el_gusto\toevoegen_handler.php on line 16
<br>
Notice: Undefined index: dekblad1_zwaar_generfd in D:\Apps\Xampp\htdocs\el_gusto\toevoegen_handler.php on line 17
```

My code:

**PHP**

```
<?php

//
$datum = $_POST['datum'];
$merk = $_POST['merk'];
$module = $_POST['module'];
$comm_naam = $_POST['comm_naam'];
$land = $_POST['land'];
$locatie = $_POST['locatie'];
$prijs = $_POST['prijs'];

//KOUD
//KOUD - DEKBLAD
line 14 $dekblad1_glad = $_POST['dekblad1_glad'];
line 15 $dekblad1_licht_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_licht_generfd'];
line 16 $dekblad1_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_generfd'];
line 17 $dekblad1_zwaar_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_zwaar_generfd'];
line 8 $dekblad1_grof_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd'];

if($dekblad1_glad=="on") $dekblad1_glad=1; else $dekblad1_glad=0;
if($dekblad1_licht_generfd=="on") $dekblad1_licht_generfd=1; else                         $dekblad1_licht_generfd=0;
if($dekblad1_generfd=="on") $dekblad1_generfd=1; else $dekblad1_generfd=0;
if($dekblad1_zwaar_generfd=="on") $dekblad1_zwaar_generfd=1; else $dekblad1_zwaar_generfd=0;
if($dekblad1_grof_generfd=="on") $dekblad1_grof_generfd=1; else $dekblad1_grof_generfd=0;

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Couldn't connect to the database!");
mysql_select_db("el_gusto") or die ("Couldn't find db!");

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sigaren(datum, merk, module, comm_naam, land, locatie, prijs, dekblad1_glad, dekblad1_licht_generfd, dekblad1_generfd, dekblad1_zwaar_generfd, dekblad1_grof_generfd) VALUES('$datum','$merk','$module','$comm_naam','$land','$locatie','$prijs','$dekblad1_glad','$dekblad1_licht_generfd','$dekblad1_generfd','$dekblad1_zwaar_generfd','$dekblad1_grof_generfd')");

if($query) {
    echo "Toevoeging gelukt!";  
}
else{
    echo mysql_error(); 
}   

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='checkbox' name="dekblad1_glad" value="1">glad
<input type='checkbox' name="dekblad1_licht_generfd" value="1">licht generfd
<input type='checkbox' name="dekblad1_generfd" value="1">generfd
<input type='checkbox' name="dekblad1_zwaar_generfd" value="1">zwaar generfd
<input type='checkbox' name="dekblad1_grof_generfd" value="1">grof generfd
```

Cheers for the help and taking time for reading this!

Comment: use `isset` to check when post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting `$dekblad1_grof_generfd`

Do something like:

```
$dekblad1_grof_generfd = isset($_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd']) ? $_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd'] : 'Default Value'; // or ''
```

Similarly, for all variables, else they will produce similar notice.

Also check [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Error is dekblad1_grof_generfd is not defined in

```
$_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd']
```

Comment: $dekblad1_glad = $_POST['dekblad1_glad'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_glad'] : null;
$dekblad1_licht_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_licht_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_generfd'] : null;
$dekblad1_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_generfd'] : null;
$dekblad1_zwaar_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_zwaar_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_zwaar_generfd'] : null;
$dekblad1_grof_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd'] : null;

I did the above and still getting the error..

Comment: Even if I drop this line:

if($dekblad1_grof_generfd=="on") <= the condition

I still get the error..

Comment: @user3360972 dont set `null`. some value. :)

Comment: @user3360972 `null` means it is not set apparently.

Comment: $dekblad1_glad = $_POST['dekblad1_glad'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_glad'] : 0;
$dekblad1_licht_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_licht_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_generfd'] : 0;
$dekblad1_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_generfd'] : 0;
$dekblad1_zwaar_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_zwaar_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_zwaar_generfd'] : 0;
$dekblad1_grof_generfd = $_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd'] ? $_POST['dekblad1_grof_generfd'] : 0;

still same error...

Comment: Cheers great solution!

Comment: @user3360972 i feel ashamed, should have guessed that sooner. :( anyway... glad i could help. :)

Comment: Hey you helped and gave me the solution! Nothing more you could've done then that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give a little bit more HTML code. At this point I don't see if you're using GET or POST method so no content is being passed from your checkboxes.
For more information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: It's POST... (short version)

  <form action="toevoegen_handler.php" method="post">

                ....

  <input type='submit' name="Toevoegen" value='Toevoegen'>
  
  </form>